# how to update table from select statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can i update a table from select statement results.  Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT count(distinct r.[ID])as Total
  FROM Table1 r left join
  Tabel2 a
  on r.ID = a.ID
  where a.Status is null
```

and here is like what i want to do and i know it is wrong:

```
update MyTable
set mycol = total
from
(
SELECT count(distinct r.[ID])as Total
      FROM Table1 r left join
      Tabel2 a
      on r.ID = a.ID
      where a.Status is null)
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `MyTable`, `Table1`, and `Table2`?  I'm assuming that you don't want every row in `MyTable` to have the same value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the subquery in the `set`:

```
update MyTable
set mycol = (
  SELECT count(distinct r.[ID])
  FROM Table1 r left join
  Tabel2 a
  on r.ID = a.ID
  where a.Status is null
)
```

Comment: thanks.  it is not updating at all.  it says the number of rows updated is 0.  when i run the select statement itself, i get 135 but when i run with the update qry then it does not update it at all!!!

Comment: it is funny, it does not like the null values initially.  i put some fake numbers then the update qry worked.  thanks

Comment: @moe: The query updates all records in the table. If there are zero records, all the zero records will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is make a couple tiny changes. Below is the code you will need to use:

```
update MyTable
set mycol = (SELECT count(distinct r.[ID])as Total
  FROM Table1 r left join
  Tabel2 a
  on r.ID = a.ID
  where a.Status is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case that, as I assume, you have multiple rows in both tables and you want to update the first table row-by-row with related results from your subquery, you'll want to add a join (assuming that both datasets will have what i am calling 'identifyingfield' below) :

```
Update MyTable
set mycol = b.total
from
MyTable a
inner join 
(
  SELECT identifyingfield, count(distinct r.[ID])
  FROM Table1 r left join
  Tabel2 a
  on r.ID = a.ID
  where a.Status is null
  group by identifyingfield
) b
ON a.identifyingfield = b.identifyingfield
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try something like this:

```
with "sums"
as
(
  select 
    F."id"
  , "sum" = sum( F."value" ) over ( partition by F."id" )
  from
    "foo" F
)
update 
  B
set
  B."totals" = S."sum"
from
  "bar" B 
  inner join "sums" S
    on S."id" = B."id";
```

[see sql-fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8921f/28/0)